# CloudFormation specify None value for parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am writing a cloudformation template and have a parameter to take in a set of configuration values for AWS resources. One of the value is `None` as specified on the AWS documentation. However when I input `null` into the cloudformation, the stack fails with:

```
Template validation error: [/Parameters/.../AllowedValues/1] 'null' values are not allowed in templates.
```

For example setting one of the many configurations for elastic beanstalk which  defaults to `None`:

```
Parameters:
  EC2KeyPairName:
    Description: EC2 key pair name for SSH access
    Type: AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName
    Default: null

Resources:
  Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: !Ref Application
      SolutionStackName: !FindInMap [ StackMap, !Ref StackType, stackName ]
      OptionSettings:
        - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
          OptionName: EC2KeyName
          Value: !Ref EC2KeyPairName
```

How do I use the `None` value as one of the options for the parameter?

Comment: Could you please provide the snippet of cloudformation code which is throwing the error, or which service & configuration parameter you are trying to set?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is documented as [Pseudo parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/pseudo-parameter-reference.html) on AWS.

Using `AWS::NoValue` sets the None value for the cloudformation templates.